# Searching SQLite Database with Python Variables

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that I'd like to search using Python variables as in:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM list WHERE InstitutionName=Variable")
```

Ideally this would allow me to return each row as a list to a larger list that contains all the rows a user is searching for. I realize what I have above is pseudocode. How could I actually write it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that you want to use the parameter substitution feature:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM list WHERE InstitutionName=?", (Variable,))
```

There's more documentation in the [actual execute command](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) and in the 4th example code box on the [sqlite3 docs page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

Note that you should *explicitly not use the `%` or `format` function* as this is susceptible to injection attacks:

```
# NEVER DO THIS
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM list WHERE InstitutionName='%s'" % (Variable,))
```

Comment: I'd give you an up vote if I had enough reputation! This is exactly what I was looking to do! Thank you so much<3

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display multiple records from database then you can use the (LIKE) keyword in your sql query:

```
("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE name LIKE'%?%'",(Variable,))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LIKE

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM list WHERE InstitutionName like '%'||?||'%'", (Variable,))
```