# How do i check if a row exists in sqlite table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to check if a row exist in an sqlite3 table in python. i want to check if there is an existing username in the table. my function is a class method
here is my code method.

```
def usercheck(self,username):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(self.db)
    c=conn.cursor()
    try :
        user=c.execute("SELECT True FROM Users  WHERE Username= %s " %(username)).fetchone()
        if user != None:
            return True
        else :
            return False

    except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
        print(' AN ERROR OCCURED')
        raise 
    conn.close() 

usercheck('admin')
```

But i get an error saying no such column

```
 user=c.execute("SELECT True FROM Users  WHERE Username= %s " %(username)).fetchone()
 sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: admin
```

I have aslo tried it this way

```
user=c.execute("SELECT True FROM Users  WHERE Username= ? " (username)).fetchone()
```

I got a differet error code

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You're using string interpolation rather than binding your username, meaning that it's being interpreted as a column; you need to use [bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949833/searching-sqlite-database-with-python-variables). When in this situation always look at the actual SQL being executed, and the issue often becomes much clearer.

Comment: i have also tried  it this way and it give an error too. TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: `user=c.execute("select 1 from users where username = ?", username).fetchone()`. You're missing a comma, leading to `(username)` being interpreted as a method

Comment: it gives this error  ''' sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied. '''

Comment: 'user=c.execute("SELECT 1 FROM Users  WHERE Username= ? " ,(username,)).fetchone()'  . i finally did it. I made the username become seem like a tuple by adding a ',' after it inside the pareenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
user=c.execute("SELECT True FROM Users  WHERE Username= %s ",(username,)).fetchone()
```